# I’m not seeing crashes in Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, carthage

I update my fabric to Crashlytics and I am using Carthage.
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/carthage/
These are steps that I installed firebase.
Everything is good like analytics and notification. but I’m not seeing crashes in Firebase Crashlytics.
I can see "Submitting report" in the console but I can't see submitting successfully.
[image: app console]
I did a manual and auto-send report. but nothing works.
please help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please check image]

Put this in runscript

```
"find ${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}" -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} "$PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "$PODS_ROOT/../GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios \{\}"
```

and put this input files

1. $(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}
```

After than put manual crash on debug and after that crashed app open two to three times same crash and refresh window you can see crash now

Happy coding:P

Comment: well, it is auto upload for DSYM files. I upload DSYM manually. I don't need this for now. In the console, I have a Submitting report message. Everything is working. it finds crashes and the number of crashes, it's trying to send, but it didn't send